# Can I log an exception thrown and caught in 3rd-party (external) library?

Tags: java, exception

My application uses some third-party libraries. I need to log some exceptions that occur inside  lib (e.g. exceptions about read file), but these exceptions are caught in the same library.

Is there some way I can log these exceptions myself, even if they're not logged by the library?

Comment: If a exception is hidden in catch clause, you will never see it. Why would you want to deal with it any further ?

Comment: @user710818 are you able to turn up the logging level in the library to get it to do the logging for you?

Comment: isn't the lib is doing this already ?

Comment: no, lib written bad - only hide this exception

Comment: @Santosh you could have edited the title too :)

Comment: Well only way seems, is to look at its source code (if available) and change the catch blocks.

Comment: @Santosh it is possible using AspectJ...look at my response below

Comment: Please fix that missleading wording of your question. You certainly don't need to _register_ exceptions and the exceptioins are certainly not _hidden_ in the library.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible without some byte code re-engineering.

Comment: Edited post title/content for clarity and searchability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [AspectJ](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/09/using-aspectjs-afterthrowing-advice-in.html). You can write an `advice` around construction (and maybe even thrwoing) of the `FileNotFoundException`. Be advised though, that it will log every time the the pointcut is reached. With some expertise you will be able to control it.

EDIT: Dave Newtwon pointed at [at this example](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/09/using-aspectjs-afterthrowing-advice-in.html) which shows how easy it is to do this once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I guess the OP says the the exceptions are eaten by the libs and not thrown.

Comment: @Santosh it is non-trivial. Look at the documentation and tutorial at the link.

Comment: And Hemal is saying you can target that using AspectJ, [as shown here](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/09/using-aspectjs-afterthrowing-advice-in.html).

Comment: @HemalPandya It's pretty trivial.

Comment: @Dave you are smarter then me :)

Comment: @HemalPandya Nah, just used AOP for awhile :)

Comment: @Dave is it possible that I might have considered the entire concept of AOP non-trivial and intended for those with time an inclination to spend time understanding the concept, that I might have thought that while a 7 line aspect itself is trivial with conceptual understanding the concept of AOP and AspectJ, of the choice between LTW and CTW, the choice between annotations or not is non-trivial and preferred for OP to indulge in some self-study instead of relying on spoon feeding which seems to be so rampant on SO?

Comment: Everyone treats AOP and AspectJ like some sort of black art. It's not. One way to demystify the complex is to present trivial examples. Trivial examples lead to experimentation and either abandonment, if it's too far beyond the learner, or enlightenment, if they stick with it. I choose the route of getting peoples' hands dirty, early and often, because success breeds success. YMMV.

Comment: @Dave I felt you were trivializing it. I like dirty hands myself and agree with you on getting a quick start without getting into all details but would have put in a note of caution if I was editing someone else's post. Lets's not drag this too much, it's all good :)

Comment: Hemal, Dev, the example given mentions method sneeze() which throwing exception. That's not the case of OP (otherwise exception reaches to his code anyways) . Its case where in an exception is thrown in sneeze() and caught within. How AspectJ is going to help in this case ?

Comment: @Santosh the advice in the aspect in the example that Dave mentions gets executed irrespective of whether and where the exception is caught. The pointcut in the example is on any method throwing an Exception. It can be adapted to any method throwing FileNotFoundException. I urge you to try it out, its pretty amazing how well it works.